# Count the number of checks each method had to perform before fully sorting the array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

So I'm writing a program that compares Bubble, Selection, Merge, and Quick Sort.  All 4 methods are given a randomized array of 1000 elements and I count to see how many times it takes a method to perform to fully sort the array.  My question revolves around the placement of my counts.  I know I should look at the Big O complexities for each to get a ballpark estimate of the number but I'm just asking if I put the counts in the right spots.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortingComparison1 
{
   //Creates class variables
   static Random random = new Random();
   static int bubbleCount = 0;
   static int totalBubbleCount = 0;
   static int totalSelectionCount = 0;
   static int totalMergeCount = 0;
   static int totalQuickCount = 0;
   static int mergeCount = 0;
   static int selectionCount = 0;
   static int quickCount = 0;
   static int [] arr;
   static int [] copyArr;
   static int [] copyArr2;
   static int [] copyArr3;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to the sort tester.");
    //runs this 20 times
    for(int i = 0; i <20; i++)
    {
        //assigns array arr to the gen array method
        arr = generateRandomArray();
        //creates copy arrays and copies the arr array
        copyArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        copyArr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        copyArr3 = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        //Call each method for the different sorts
        System.out.println();
        bubble();
        System.out.println();
        selection();
        System.out.println();
        merge();
        System.out.println();
        quick();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The average number of checks were:");
    System.out.println("Bubble Count " + (totalBubbleCount / 20));
    System.out.println("Selection Count " + (totalSelectionCount / 20));
    System.out.println("Merge Count "+ (totalMergeCount / 20));
    System.out.println("QuickSort Count " + (totalQuickCount / 20));
}

public static void bubble()
{
    //assigns int[]a to arr
    int[] a = arr;
    System.out.println("Array Before Bubble Sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        //Prints out unsorted array
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    //sorts array with bubble sort method
    bubbleSort(a);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        //Prints out bubble sorted array
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    //Prints out number of checks to sort array
    System.out.println("Bubble checks: " + bubbleCount);
    totalBubbleCount += bubbleCount;
    //resets bubbleCount
    bubbleCount = 0;
}

public static void selection()
{
    // assigns int[] a to the copied array
    int[] a = copyArr;
    System.out.println("Array Before Selection Sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        //Prints out unsorted array
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    //sorts int[] a with selection sort
    selectionSort(a);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Array After Selection Sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        //Prints out selection sorted array
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    //Prints out number of selections counts
    System.out.println("Selection checks: " + selectionCount);
    totalSelectionCount += selectionCount;
    //resets selectionCount
    selectionCount = 0;
}

public static void merge()
{   
    //assigns int[] a to second copied array
    int[] a = copyArr2;
    System.out.println("Array Before Merge Sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        //Prints unsorted array
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    //sorts array with mergeSort method
    mergeSort(a);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Array After Merge Sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        //Prints out merge sorted array
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    //Prints out number of checks
    System.out.println("Merge checks: " + mergeCount);
    totalMergeCount += mergeCount;
    //resets mergeCount
    mergeCount  = 0;
}

public static void quick()
{
    //assigns int[] a to third copied array
    int[] a = copyArr3;
    System.out.println("Array Before Quick Sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        //Prints out unsorted array
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    //sorts array by calling quickSort method
    quickSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Array After Quick Sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        //Prints out quick sorted array
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    //prints out quickCount and resets quickCount back to 0
    System.out.println("QuickSort checks: " + quickCount);
    totalQuickCount += quickCount;
    //prints avg num of checks
    quickCount = 0;
}

private static int[] generateRandomArray() 
{
    //generates array of size 1000 and fill it with random numbers, 0-999
    int size = 20;
    int[] a = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        a[i] = random.nextInt(1000);
    }
    return a;       
}

public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] a)
{
    boolean done = false;
    int n = a.length;
    while(done == false)//runs n times
    {
        done = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)//runs n times
        {

            if(a[i] > a[i+1])//Swap
            {
                bubbleCount++;
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                done = false;
            }

        }
    }
    return a;
}

public static void mergeSort(int [] a)
{
    //put counter for checks inside method
    int size = a.length;
    if(size < 2)//Halt recursion
    {
        return;
    }
    int mid = size/ 2;
    int leftSize = mid;
    int rightSize = size - mid;
    int[] left = new int[leftSize];
    int[] right = new int[rightSize];
    //populate left
    for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
    {
        mergeCount++;
        left[i] = a[i];
    }
    //populate right
    for(int i = mid; i < size; i++)
    {
        mergeCount++;
        right[i-mid] = a[i];
    }
    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    //merge
    merge(left, right, a);
}

public static void merge(int[] left, int[] right, int[] a)
{
    int leftSize = left.length;
    int rightSize = right.length;
    int i = 0;//index for left
    int j = 0;//index for right
    int k = 0;//index for a
    while(i < leftSize && j < rightSize)//compares until the end is reach in either 
    {
        if(left[i] <= right[j])
        {
            //assigns a[k] to left[i] and increments both i and k
            a[k] = left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            //assigns a[k] to right [j] and increments j  and k
            a[k] = right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    //fills in the rest
    while(i<leftSize)
    {
        a[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<rightSize)
    {
        a[k] = right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

public static void selectionSort(int[] a )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) 
    {
        int pos = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) 
        {
            // increments selection count
            selectionCount++;
            // if a[j] is less than a[pos], set pos to j
            if (a[j] < a[pos]) 
            {
                pos = j;
            }   
        }

        // swaps a[i] and a[pos]
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[pos];
        a[pos] = temp;
    }
}
public static void quickSort(int[] a, int left, int right)
{
    int index = partition(a, left, right);
    if(left < index - 1)
    {
        //increments quickCount and calls quickSort recursively
        quickCount++;
        quickSort(a, left, index-1);    
    }
    if(index < right)
    {
        //increments quickCount and calls quicSort recursively
        quickCount++;
        quickSort(a, index, right);
    }
}
public static int partition(int[] a, int left, int right)
{
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    int pivot = a[((left+right)/2)];
    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(a[i] < pivot)
        {
            i++;//correct position so move forward
        }
        while(a[j] > pivot)
        {
            j--;//correct position 
        }
        if(i <= j)
        {
            //swaps and increments i and decrements j
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
}
```

Comment: What are you countng?  Comparisons or swaps?  Right now it looks like your counts are not counting either one correctly.

Comment: Well I'm trying to count how many times it takes to a sort an array, but I think I'm just going to end up doing comparisons.  I moved the bubbleCount right above the if statement, moved the mergeCount into the merge method in the first while loop, and then I moved the quickCount into the partition method where a[i] is < or > the pivot.  So hopefully that is right. @JS1

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please declare your [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35518025/1157100).

Answer (score 2):

#### Magic number

`20` - the number of iterations - should be replaced with a `static final` variable, so that you can freely modify the number of iterations to perform.

#### Printing arrays

[`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) gives you a nice `String` representation for printing to the console, so you do not have to loop yourself.

#### Too much `static`

You are currently using too many `static` variables to store your data *and* counts, and that can make it unwieldy.

#### An alternative modeling approach

How about considering that each test should implement an `interface` that provides a count of every run, and other useful metrics?

```
public interface Sorter {

    /**
     * Sorts an array.
     *
     * @param the array to sort
     * @return the number of steps it takes to sort an array
     */
    int sort(int[] array);

    /**
     * Gets the number of method calls to {@link #sort(int[])} so far.
     *
     * @return the number of iterations done
     */
    int getIterations();

    /**
     * Gets the total sorting count so far.
     *
     * @return the total number of sorting steps done
     */
    long getTotalCount();
}
```

Then you can have implementations...

```
public class BubbleSorter implements Sorter {

    int iterations = 0;
    long totalCount = 0;

    @Override
    public int sort(int[] array) {
        int countResult = 0;
        // do sorting while calling countResult++ where appropriate
        iterations++;
        totalCount += countResult;
        return countResult;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIterations() {
        return iterations;
    }

    public long getTotalCount() {
        return totalCount;
    }
}
```

You can then rely on the methods to give you your results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sorter bubbleSort = new BubbleSorter();
    int lastCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        lastCount = bubbleSort.sort(getNewRandomArray());
    }
    System.out.println("Last count: " + lastCount);
    System.out.println("Average: " +
            ((bubbleSort.getTotalCount() * 1.0) / bubbleSort.getIterations());
}
```

Note that this simplified approach does not take multi-threading into consideration. With some slight tweaks to how `iterations` and `totalCount` can be accumulated in a thread-safe manner, making calls to each sorting algorithms' `sort()` method concurrently to reduce execution time is certainly achievable.